# Is there a way we can force the SharePoint 2013 sites/pages to use Desktop View when using iPad device

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, mobile

Mobile Browser View feature doesn't seems to be a solution.

In other words, can we disable responsive design when using iPad device?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure SharePoint 2013 offers "Responsive" design.
Nevertheless, inside the VirtualDirectories/[your web app]/App_Browsers folder of IIS you will find a "compat.browser" file.
It might be have the answers you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the compat.browser file as suggested above you will need to find each device type that you want to force to desktop view, and change this line:

```
<capability name="isMobileDevice" value="true" />
```

to this

```
<capability name="isMobileDevice" value="false" />
```